# CMax: (New in circuits)

Tags: resistors

I've been working on circuits lately (still a beginner), and I was introduced to a "program" (i'm not sure of its actual name) CMax. Could anyone explain how the connections of wires/resistors/pot-s work in it? I tried google-ing, but it didn't really help...
Thank you!

Comment: Please post a link to the site on the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program seems to be emulating a standard solderless breadboard, and I guess it might be confusing at first if you haven't physically worked with one before.

In the breadboard, the long bars at the top and bottom are all horizontally connected, these are typically used for power and ground rails.

In the center are two rows of several 5 hole columns. These 5 holes are all electrically connected together vertically. When you put two legs of a component in the same electrically shorted region, they become connected. So if you want to attach one end of a resistor to a wire, you can put the resistor leg in A1, and the wire pin in B1, and then they are logically connected together. Circles in the image show examples of the areas that are logically connected (every hole inside a circle is connected to every other hole in that same circle).

[image]

Comment: Your followup question is too vague to answer, but here's another connection diagram if you're still confused: http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mathys/ecen2250/myDAQ01/breadboard_90.png